# Shell script change directory with variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but I still could not find any good solution. Hence, asking it again if anyone can help !!

I am trying to change a my working directory inside a shell script with help of a variable. But I get `" No such file or directory"` everytime.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${RED_INSTANCE_NAME}   <-- This correctly displays the directory name
cd $RED_INSTANCE_NAME       <-- This line gives the error
```

Now, when I try to give the actually directory name instead of using the variable, shell changes the directory without issues

```
cd test  <-- No error
```

Does anyone knows what can be the issue here ? Please help !!

Comment: How are you setting the value of `RED_INSTANCE_NAME`?

Comment: Try saying `cd "${RED_INSTANCE_NAME}"`

Comment: If you think this question has already been asked, it might be good to link to those similar questions and explain why the answers are not right for you.

Comment: you could use the echo command like this to see if any other character is in the var value: echo "'${RED_INSTANCE_NAME}'"

Comment: I'd also drop a `pwd` into your script to validate that the script thinks it's in the right directory; and possible an `ls -F` as well. What you're doing should work, so it will either be spaces in the directory name, confusion over case, leading/trailing white space (or other unprintable character), or the script isn't running from where you think it's running from.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You variable contains a carriage return.  Try saying:

```
cd $(echo $RED_INSTANCE_NAME | tr -d '\r')
```

and it should work.  In order to remove the CR from the variable you can say:

```
RED_INSTANCE_NAME=$(echo $RED_INSTANCE_NAME | tr -d '\r')
```

---

The following would illustrate the issue:

```
$ mkdir abc
$ foo=abc$'\r'
$ echo "${foo}"
abc
$ cd "${foo}"
: No such file or directory
$ echo $foo | od -x
0000000 6261 0d63 000a
0000005
$ echo $foo | tr -d '\r' | od -x
0000000 6261 0a63
0000004
$ echo $'\r' | od -x
0000000 0a0d
0000002
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I indeed had a carriage return at the end of variable.

Comment: or `cd \`echo $RED_INSTANCE_NAME | tr -d '\r'\``

Answer (score 29):

One way to encounter your described problem is to have a tilde (`~`) in the variable name. Use the absolute path or `$HOME` variable instead. Note that using `$HOME` will require double quotations.

```
# doesn't work
$ vartilde='~/'
$ cd $vartilde
-bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory

# works
$ varfullpath='/Users/recurvirostridae'
$ cd $varfullpath

# works
$ varwithhome="$HOME"
$ cd $varwithhome
```

Comment: I also had `~` in my variable. Thank you for the `$HOME` suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
cd "$RED_INSTANCE_NAME"
```

Also, make sure the path makes sense to the current directory where `cd` command is executed.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I tried this way too. But no help. it still gives the error !! And yes, I am sure that I am executing this command in correct directory

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Try running via "bash -x" to see what it executes.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a different issue.  My "cd $newDir" was failing because I added logging into my script. Apparently if you add a pipe to any cd command it does nothing or gets gobbled up.

Wasted 3 hours figuring that out.

```
newDir=$oldDir/more/dirs/

cd $newDir #works

cd $newDir | tee -a log #does nothing

cd $newdir | echo hi    #does nothing
```

So cd with any pipe does nothing. No idea why cd fails. The pipe means finish what command you doing then feed any output to next command. This is on RHEL 7.
I was trying to log all my commands and hit this nice error. Figured I'd post it in case anyone else hits it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for carriage returns, ANSI escapes and other special characters with

```
cat -v <<< "$RED_INSTANCE_NAME"
```

This will show all the characters that `echo $RED_INSTANCE_NAME` would just hide or ignore.

In particular, if your error message is `: No such file or directory` as opposed to `bash: cd: yourdir: No such file or directory`, it means you have a carriage return at the end of your variable, probably from reading it from a DOS formatted file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is going wrong for you, but I can offer one piece of general advice:

```
cd "$RED_INSTANCE_NAME"       # Quote the string in case it has spaces.error
```

You should nearly always put the "$VARIABLE" in quotes.  This will protect from surprises when the value of the variable contains funny stuff (like spaces).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I tried this way too. But no help. it still gives the error !!