# Cannot cd with external variable in bash script

Tags: bash

In a bash script
I want to do that but it doesn't work

**config.txt** :

```
newdir="build/src"
```

**script.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash


source config.txt
cd $newdir
```

> : No file or folder of this type

I have this with bash +x script.sh

```
+ source config.txt
++ newdir=$'build/src\r'
+ cd $'build/src\r'
: Aucun fichier de ce type
```

Comment: bash is *Case-Sensitive*.... and `source` is a keyword in bash you should use another variable name, e.g. `newdir="build/src"` then `source config.txt` and `cd "$newdir"`.

Comment: it doesn't work too with an other name

Comment: What you call the variable make no difference at all -- you just want a name that doesn't conflict with a reserved word.  Do this run your `script.sh` as `bash -x script.sh` and post the output to tell us where it is failing. Just add it to your question (with each line indented by 4-spaces so it formats correctly) and that will tell us exactly what is going on. You still have `source config.txt` unchanged - right? And the `build/src` directory is in the current working directory when you run the script right? The `config.txt` file is also in that same directory too?

Comment: `\r` by the end of your file path is part of a Window's linefeed, you will want to remove it (retype the path by hand). The error appear as an empty filename because `\r` is the carriage return char which makes the cursor go back to the start of the line, where `: No file or folder of this type` will overwrite the file name

Comment: your path is relative, so, when you run this script, you should be in folder that contains build/src or change it and using an absolute path

Comment: How can I remove this (I'm on notepad ++ encoded in UTF-8) ?

Comment: Actually I think the config.txt file has the following content : `newdir="build/src"\r\n`, so retyping the path only won't solve your problem, you either need to delete the invisible char that precedes the end of the line, use a tool that will remove all `\r` (dos2unix if available, tr or sed otherwise) or rewrite the whole file

Comment: With Notepad++ use `Edit` -> `EOL Conversion` -> `Unix (LF)` in the menus ; you will probably see that the `Windows (CR LF)` menu item is grayed since that's your current linefeeds style (or in the status bar at the bottom of the window you can see "Windows (CR LF)" as the third item from the right)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it works well !

Comment: Glad to hear it !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script change directory with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281328/shell-script-change-directory-with-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem came from invsible `\r` (carriage return) generated by windows at the end of lines. 
I change the EOL Conversion to `Unix (LF)`!